# OpenFileDialog using

Tags: file-upload, ext.net, filefilter

I am using Ext.Net.I want to use OpenFileDiaolog filter in aspx.(in fileuploadfield tag)
Is it impossible ?

this is my aspx code:

```
<ext:FileUploadField ID="uploadAlani1" runat="server" Width="150" Icon="Attach" Text="Örnek Dosya"  >



    <DirectEvents>
        <Change OnEvent="DosyaSec" IsUpload="true"></Change>
    </DirectEvents>

</ext:FileUploadField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: click to "DosyaSec" and press to F12 and redirected code behind. Maybe help you.